# Send email that contains a link with your id

Tags: php

I have this form

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="forgot.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Please enter your email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "row">
        <a class= "btn btn-success pull-right" href= "index.php">Back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Which goes here:

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require "connection.php";
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users where email = '$email' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);




$message ="Please click here to create a new password www.jasmine.com/id?=" . $row['id'];
$from = 'From: jazz@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Change password';
$body = "E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";




if($row)
{
    mail ($email, $subject, $body, $from);
    echo "Please check your email";
}
}
else
{
echo  "Email Not Found";
}
?>
```

When I put my email, it outputs "Please check your email" but when I do I did receive anything, Also I want to receive that link with my `$id` attached so in the third page Ill have a form requesting to change my password, by the id. My only problem now is that the email is not sending?

It doesnt send, and I get this error

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50541 Library:50629 in /var/www/ml/public/new_system/connection.php on line 4
```

Line 4 is `require "connection.php"`

Comment: Look up the parameters for a `mail()` function [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Also, the second parameter of `mail()` is the subject - not the body, so you're missing a parameter here.

Comment: The way I did $id is correct?

Comment: and mail expects an email address for `From:` not a website

Comment: ok but it still didnt work

Comment: I edited the question @RiggsFolly

Comment: I edited the question  @Fred-ii-

Comment: So it looks like you have an issue with the `php_mysqli` extension in PHP. Is this the first time you tried to use `mysqli_`?

Comment: no I have used it before, and before my edit, the email worked fine for other programs I have done it with, but because this time I want the id embedded in the link, it isnt working @RiggsFolly